# How to display my calculated TZ in jquery datetimepicker?

Tags: jquery, timezone, datetimepicker

I am trying to have TZ displayed with date time when using datetimepicker.

calculating TZ as: refer:

[script for javascript TZ info](http://pellepim.bitbucket.org/jstz/)

```
var userTimeZone = jstz.determine();  //from jstz-1.0.4.min.js
var userTimeZoneName = userTimeZone.name();   //"America/Chicago"
```

now I want to attache it to the result of the datetimepicker, like this:

```
$('#dateRangeStart').datetimepicker({
            dateFormat: $.datepicker.ATOM,      //$.datepicker.ATOM = 2015-01-14 13:22   RFC_2822=Thu, 8 Jan 2015 13:22
            minDate: dtStart,
            maxDate: new Date(Date.parse($("#dateRangeEnd").val().replace(/ /,'T'))),  //dtEnd,
            onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
                //formatting
                dateText = dateText+' '+userTimeZoneName;
                $("#dateRangeStart").val(dateText);
                }

            },
            onSelect: function (selectedDateTime){
                var start = $(this).datetimepicker('getDate');
                $('#dateRangeEnd').datetimepicker('option', 'minDate', new Date(start.getTime()));
            }
        });
```

My objective is to display date as: **2015-01-06 08:13 America/Chicago**

Pl advice how to accomplish this? I want to send this TZ info to backend.